# Computing Steady Probabilities for Markov Process

Tags: python, markov-process, computational-statistics

I hope I am asking this question on the correct SE, if not, please redirect it.

I am trying to compute steady state probabilities for a Markov process using python. Knowing the transition rate values I calculated the transition probabilities in the form

$p_{ij}(\Delta{t})=\int_{0}^{\Delta{t}}r_{ij}e^{-r_{ij}t}\mathrm{d}t$

I choose a very small $\Delta{t}$ and use the the approximation $e^x=1+x$. I calculate no transition probability using $p_{ii}=1-\sum_{i\neq{j}}p_{ij}$ to construct the state transition matrix, $P$.

After that I iteratively take square of the $P$, i.e.,

> ```
>  for i in range(iteration):
>         B=np.matmul(P,P)
>         P=B
> ```

However, probably due to accumulation of machine precision errors in Python, the summation of all elements in a row do not add up to 1. For small values of iteration, it sum is very close to 1, however as iteration value increases, it starts increasing.

How should I handle this? I thought of two possibilities:

- Choose the largest iteration value for which the summation is close enough to 1.
- Normalize $B$ at each step, i.e.,

> ```
>  for i in range(iteration):
>         B=np.matmul(P,P)
>         P=B/sum(B[0])
> ```

Is there an advantage of any of these methods? Or is there a better method to handle this problem?

Comment: Hi, welcome. I think this question better be asked at Stack Overflow. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522933/python-floating-point-arbitrary-precision-available

Comment: Your edit suggests a reasonable & on topic question. However, neither the title nor the body imply that's what you're asking. It's OK to mention Python & to show example code, but please edit this to focus on the fact that you are asking for strategies to deal w/ finite precision from a theoretical perspective.